# Mock Object variable in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-2.4

I want to create a test for the following function in Cakephp2.0 with PHPUnit:

```
public function matching($check, $field) {

    $return = true;
    foreach ($check as $c) {
        if ($c != $this->data['User'][$field]) {
            $return = false;
        }         
    }

    return $return;
}
```

How do I set the value of:

```
$this->data['User'][$field]
```

My test function is:

```
public function testMatching() {
    $this->data['User']['password'] = 'testpass';
    $check = array('testpass');
    $result = $this->User->matching($check, 'password');
    $this->assertEquals(true, $result);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're assigning the data using $this in the test case. You should assign it to the object under test

Comment: Hi, thanks but i'm not sure i understand what you mean.  Could you give me an example

Comment: when you do $this->data['User']['password'] = 'testpass', what object is $this? the data should be assigned to the class you're testing.

Comment: Sorry, i've noticed the problem.  It should be $this->User->data = array('User' => array( 'password' => 'testpass'));